# Unable to start Workers from Spark master: Exited with code 1 exitStatus 1

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I'm experiencing the issue I mentioned in the title and I really don't know how to fix it. I tried many related answers provided solutions, forums and more, but I was not able to silence it.

I have an EC2 Ubuntu 16 machine (RAM ~32GB, ROM ~ 70GB, 8 Cores) running a standalone Spark Master. Below I show my overall configuration.

**spark-env.sh**:

```
. . .
SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS=xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077
. . .
```

**/etc/hosts**:

```
127.0.0.1 locahost localhost.domain ubuntu
::1 locahost localhost.domain ubuntu
localhost  master # master and slave have same ip
localhost  slave  # master and slave have same ip
```

I'm trying to connect to it using the following Scala code via Intellij Idea:

```
new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("my-app")
    .setMaster("spark://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7077")
    .set("spark.executor.host", "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx")
    .set("spark.executor.cores", "8")
    .set("spark.executor.memory","20g")
```

This configuration leads to the following logs.
**master.log** containing lots of lines like:

```
. . .
xx/xx/xx xx:xx:xx INFO Master: Removing executor app-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx/xx because it is EXITED
xx/xx/xx xx:xx:xx INFO Master: Launching executor app-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx/xx on worker worker-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-127.0.0.1-42524
```

**worker.log** containing lots of lines like:

```
. . .
xx/xx/xx xx:xx:xx INFO Worker: Executor app-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx/xxx finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1
xx/xx/xx xx:xx:xx INFO Worker: Asked to launch executor app-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx/xxx for my-app
xx/xx/xx xx:xx:xx INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: ubuntu
xx/xx/xx xx:xx:xx INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: ubuntu
xx/xx/xx xx:xx:xx INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
xx/xx/xx xx:xx:xx INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
xx/xx/xx xx:xx:xx INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(ubuntu); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(ubuntu); groups with modify permissions: Set()
xx/xx/xx xx:xx:xx INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre//bin/java" "-cp" "/usr/local/share/spark/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/usr/local/share/spark/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/*" "-Xmx4096M" "-Dspark.driver.port=34889" "-Dspark.cassandra.connection.port=9042" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@127.0.0.1:34889" "--executor-id" "476" "--hostname" "127.0.0.1" "--cores" "1" "--app-id" "app-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@127.0.0.1:42524"
```

If you want, [here's a Gist](https://gist.github.com/AndreaM16/098bdec3f6a4a490db421da629892de8) containing the logs lines I put above.

If I try the following basic configuration, I have 0 errors but my application just hangs on, the server really does nothing. No CPU/RAM utilization.

```
new SparkConf()
              .setAppName("my-app")
              .setMaster("spark://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7077")
```

> On `/etc/hosts` I set both master and slave to the same ip. Scala version `2.11.6` on both server and `build.sbt`. Spark version `2.1.1` both on server and on `build.sbt`.

Here are some Spark-UI screens:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So, I would like to:

- Launch a task from my pc
- Work on that task on the server
- Get results on my pc

I'm guessing, **Can It be a bad resource configuration? If not, what may be causing this? How should I tune my configuration to avoid such issue?**.

If you need more details just ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I want my personal computer to orchestrate, I changed my configuration setting it as master and server as executor.

So, my **conf/spark-env.sh** would be:

```
# Options read by executors and drivers running inside the cluster
SPARK_LOCAL_IP=localhost #o set the IP address Spark binds to on this node
SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS=xx.xxx.xxx.xxx #PUBLIC SERVER IP
```

**conf/slaves**:

```
# A Spark Worker will be started on each of the machines listed below.
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx #PUBLIC SERVER IP
```

**/etc/hosts**:

```
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx master #PUBLIC SERVER IP
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx slave  #PUBLIC SERVER IP
```

And finally Scala configuration would be:

```
.setMaster("local[*]")
.set("spark.executor.host", "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx") //Public Server IP
.set("spark.executor.memory","16g")
```